# Flutter - Put a List[][] in widget Text

Tags: flutter

I have a text widget and I want to put strings from that list of lists to appear in the widget text. Example
it will get the list [0] [0] then the list [0] [1] then list [1] [0]

```
List list = [
    ['text1', 'text2'],
    ['text3']
  ];



Text(list[index])//error
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want to get all text values from the list and display them in the text widget you can try this

```
List list = [
    ['text1', 'text2'],
    ['text3']
  ];
  
  String strToDIsplay = "";
  
list.forEach((listItem){
  //The listItem variable will contain a list
  //A list of string 
  //example ['text1', 'text2']
  listItem.forEach((listSubItem){
    //The listSubItem variable will contain a String
    //example 'text1' or  'text2' etc
   strToDIsplay += (listSubItem.toString() + " ");
  });  
});
```

and then display strToDIsplay

```
Text(strToDIsplay);
```

The reason you got error while using

```
Text(list[index]);
```

is because, the list variable you have defined is a list of list Not List of string so list[index] will give you a list and since Text widget can only accept a String and not a List, you get an error. The right format would be list[index1][index2] which would return a string.  You can also try

```
Text(list[index].toString());
```

Although I doubt that is what you want

Answer (score 0):

As your `list` is `List` of `List<String>` you must use

```dart
Text(list[0][0]) // 1st String of 1st List
Text(list[0][1]) // 2nd String of 1st List...etc
```